# Is the text of a closed question indexed by Google's spider?

Tags: support, closed-questions, search-engine

Some time ago, we had a problem with [identify-my-rock](/questions/tagged/identify-my-rock)-type questions on Earth Science Stack Exchange.

After some users [complained about receiving too many of this kind of question](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/ive-had-enough-lets-ban-rock-id-questions), we closed and deleted 500 questions with some effort and we made them off-topic.

We stopped coming up as the first entry for searches for "help identify my rock" on Google, and the flood of questions ended.

However, we still receive some questions. We close them, but I realized that +2k users were not deleting them, so I made [this list of questions to delete](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/list-of-identify-my-rock-questions-to-delete). I asked for help from a mod but they don't want to delete them unilaterally.

My question is if we are at risk of appearing again at the top of Google searches if we don't delete them, because I am a bit tired of asking users to delete the questions. Apparently the problem is that delete votes don't put posts into a review queue and we don't have many +2k users using meta frequently.

Does Google index closed questions? Should I continue battling for the deletion of these unwanted questions for this reason?

Comment: I'm guessing your best bet is to take the information (yes, closed questions do show up on Google), and start (another?) meta discussion on earth science to see if the community would grant moderators the privilege of 'single-handedly' deleting these, because at that point it's not longer truly a unilateral decision...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell [done](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/ask-moderators-to-delete-identify-my-rock-questions) thanks